# Update CTE to insert create new record chaining datetimes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following CTE:

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        fromtime,
        (case 
            when datediff(day, fromtime, totime) = 0
               then totime
            else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, fromtime))
         end) as dayendtime,
        totime
    from 
        t
    union all
    select 
        dayendtime as fromtime,
        (case 
            when datediff(day, dayendtime, totime) = 0
               then totime
               else dateadd(day, 1, dayendtime)
         end) as dayendtime,
        totime
    from  
        cte
    where 
        dayendtime < totime
)
```

Which outputs data like this:

[image]

And works great, but now I want to chain create a new row chaining the `DayEndTime` to the `FromTime` of the next record if the `DayEndTime` is midnight, for example:

[image]

Can anyone give me guidance on how this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: What data are you starting with?  It seems like `t` may have the values you want to begin with.  There is no need to expand them out.

Comment: It does actually! It has the FromTime and ToTime. I need the dayendtime because I want to calculate the amount of time per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte 
as (
      select fromtime,
             (case when datediff(day, fromtime, totime) = 0
                   then totime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, fromtime))
              end) as dayendtime,
             totime
      from t
      union all
      select dayendtime as fromtime,
             (case when datediff(day, dayendtime, totime) = 0
                   then totime
                   else dateadd(day, 1, dayendtime)
              end) as dayendtime,
             totime
       from cte
       where dayendtime < totime
),
cte_new 
as (
  SELECT dayendtime AS fromtime,totime AS dayendtime,totime 
  FROM cte
  WHERE dayendtime=cast(dayendtime AS date)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cte_new
ORDER BY fromtime;
```

Comment: If you have duplicates with the same dayendtime at midnight, you will get duplicates with the new entries. Or you can do SELECT DISTINCT in cte_new